# Переклад слова "потешки"

Tags: переклад, росіянізм, from-russian

[Російська стаття Вікіпедії](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%80%D1%8B_%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0)

> Потешка — элемент педагогики, песенка-приговорка, сопутствующая игре с
>   пальцами, руками и ногами ребёнка.

[Google перекладач](https://translate.google.com.ua/m/translate#view=home&op=translate&sl=ru&tl=uk&text=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B8) подає

> потешки - потішки

Проте "потішки" немає в [словниках](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B0&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on), хоча в [Google книгах](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&ei=OEfMW8PBOYaksAH8gaLIBg&q=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%96%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B8&oq=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%96%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B8&gs_l=psy-ab.3...27916.29655.0.30173.7.7.0.0.0.0.107.610.5j2.7.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.3.271...0.0.peWOZhERaWY) зустрічається.

Як зробити нормативний переклад слова *"потешки"*?

Comment: У версії для комп'ютера гугл дає варіанти - забавлянки, забавки. Ось тут http://abetka.ukrlife.org/g_zabavy.htm є збірка ігор під назвою "Забавлянки для масажу та купання дитини".

Comment: -1: автор так і не надав перекладу цього слова своїми словами українською мовою.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перш за все, я погоджуюся із коментарем до запитання, слово "[забавлянка](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0)" буде справді хорошим відповідником. Можемо побачити це слово як переклад російського "потешки" у "[Наукових записках](https://lingvj.oa.edu.ua/assets/files/full/2013/n39/NZ_Vyp_39.pdf)" (ст. 82, див. ключові слова). Синонімами до слова забавлянка [також є](http://composer.ucoz.ua/publ/zhanri/zabavljanki/22-1-0-210): утішка, чукикалка, загурянка.

Ну а, якщо ми говоримо про "потешки" як елемент педагогіки, то можливо, що можна ще й використати слово "гра-руханка" як його відповідник (однак цього слова нема в жодних офіційних джерелах, а лише [тут](http://icesun.com.ua/node/2545) і [тут](https://studopedia.org/7-4393.html)), однак в такому випадку у нас втрачається значення "песенка-приговорка, сопутствующая игре с пальцами, руками и ногами ребёнка".